# Best garbage collector for large jpa deletion

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, cron, garbage-collection

I have a daily control of business authentication. So I can get rid of old registres. It gets around 30,000 every business day. At 23:30 my cron-job runs and delete them (code below). Problem is, it is increasing the heap size every time it runs, until the application is restarted.

In the very begging of the image is the green line of the pod that restarted. And then becomes the orange line of the new pod, that suffers and increasing in the heap size every 23:30 of business day, as said above. This application does lots of things (data base manipulation included) during the day, and its heap size keeps constant.

[7 days Heap Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGroZ.png)

Here is my first question: which GC can prevent this? (The application has no pause time requirements)

Here is my second question: is there something in my classes that can be responsible for this behaviour? (like lombok annotations, the private final attributes, the @Transactional annotation, etc)

And here are my business and jpa repository classes:

```java
/**
 * BUSINESS CLASS
 */
import arrecadacao.core.lib.repository.ArrecadacaoAutenticacaoRepository;
import arrecadacao.core.lib.repository.ArrecadacaoDataSistemaRepository;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import static arrecadacao.core.lib.type.Constantes.GERAL;
import static arrecadacao.core.lib.type.Constantes.ZONE_AMERICA_SAO_PAULO;
import static arrecadacao.job.type.ConstantesJob.LOG_ARRECADACAO_JOB;

@Slf4j
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AutenticacaoService {

    private final ArrecadacaoDataSistemaRepository arrecadacaoDataSistemaRepository;
    private final ArrecadacaoAutenticacaoRepository arrecadacaoAutenticacaoRepository;

    @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.limpa-autenticacoes}", zone = ZONE_AMERICA_SAO_PAULO)
    public void limpaAutenticacao() {

        try {
            LocalDate dataSistemaAnterior = arrecadacaoDataSistemaRepository
                    .findByNomArrecadacaoData(GERAL).get().getDatAnteriorSistema();

            Long qtdAtutenticacoesDeletadas = arrecadacaoAutenticacaoRepository
                    .deleteByDatSistemaLessThan(dataSistemaAnterior);

            log.info("{}{} autenticações anteriores a {} foram deletadas.",
                    LOG_ARRECADACAO_JOB, qtdAtutenticacoesDeletadas, dataSistemaAnterior);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("{}AutenticacaoService.limpaAutenticacao -> {}", LOG_ARRECADACAO_JOB, e);
        }
    }
}


/**
 * JPA REPOSITORY THAT GETS THE DATE
 */
import arrecadacao.core.lib.entity.ArrecadacaoDataSistema;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface ArrecadacaoDataSistemaRepository extends JpaRepository<ArrecadacaoDataSistema, Long> {

    Optional<ArrecadacaoDataSistema> findByNomArrecadacaoData(String nomArrecadacaoData);
}



/**
 * JPA REPOSITORY THAT PERFORMS THE DELETION
 */
import arrecadacao.core.lib.entity.ArrecadacaoAutenticacao;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Repository
public interface ArrecadacaoAutenticacaoRepository extends JpaRepository<ArrecadacaoAutenticacao, Long> {

    @Transactional
    Long deleteByDatSistemaLessThan(LocalDate dataSistemaAnterior);
}
```

Comment: Looking at the graph it looks like the heap doesn't grow after the 16th. Is this actually the case?

Comment: And to add a bit. Your code is, as far as I can read it, deleting posts from the DB. This has nothing to do with garbage collection in the java sense.

Comment: Hi Erik. It doesn't grow after the 16th because the cronjob only executes on weekdays. It went up again on the 18th and 19th (same pattern, about 5MB each day). Good point about deleting from the DB, any extra thoughts about the increase?

Comment: It does look like you have a memory leak. Sadly, just changing gc will not do anything about that. I would fire up a profiler like `yourkit`, run the application in a test env and look at old gen behaviour (because it's old gen that gets filled up). The profilers can show you the instances that are retained.

Comment: It seems like, even not fetching the registres to the memory, the tenured increases as long as the deleting takes place. A surprise to me, I thought jpa would delegate the deletion to the database and would only wait for the answer. I've searched for alternatives, and it looks like the best approach is to delete by chunks.

Answer (score 0):

There are some points to be verified:

1 - Are the heap memory under pressure? If your heap Xms and Xmx are higher than 65MB (looking at your screenshot) is normal to keep growing until to needs to be collected by GC.

2 - As you are doing the delete without returning all the data, probably JPA doesn't put these objects on memory. Do you get some Heap Dump to look at what kind of objects are sticking on Heap?

3 - About GCs: If you are using SerialGC (I'm presuming that, answer if I'm wrong) it is really limited and could be not enough in many cases. Could you try to force another GC (-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC or even -XX:+UseG1GC). Both have time pause, but the Serial is worse.

Well, I hope these points can help you.

Comment: Why do you assume the serial gc? While we don't know what JDK version OP is using, a better guess would be the parallell gc that is default for JDK 8 (and downwards).

Comment: I presume based on heap size of the on that picture. On micro services with very small heaps (<100M) is usual give less than 1 core of CPU resulting on a default selection of SerialGC (https://dzone.com/articles/pitfalls-in-jvm-and-docker-defaults) and (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/collectors.html).

Answer (score 0):

Considering Gilberto's comments above, I did some testing and here are my points and solution:

1 - the Heap memory available was enough, so there was no need for the GC's “stop the world” cycle. Eventually the heap was big enough and the GC performed the Major collect

2 - Apparently, SpringData and its deleteBy methods do a fetch to memory for all objects, and, only then delete the unitarly, what in case of thousand of registers can lead to timeout errors

3 - the solution was this JPQL deletion, that commands the exclusion directly to the db, without fetching the registers to memory, resulting a performance similar to native sql

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("DELETE FROM ArrecadacaoAutenticacao a " +
        "WHERE a.datSistema < :dataSistemaAnterior ")
Integer deleteByDatSistemaLessThan(LocalDate dataSistemaAnterior);
```